# How to model a stochastic sequence of events based on the probability of individual events?

Tags: probability-theory

I am struggling with a problem.

There is a sequence of independent events and we know the probability of occurrence of each event (they are not equiprobable but the probability of events are close and $P(E_1) > P(E_2) > P(E_3) > \ldots $.

We want to find the probability of occurrence of 2, 3, or 4 events in the sequence. For instance, there are 10 events as below:
$$
E_1\ E_2\ E_3\ E_4\ E_5\ E_6\ E_7\ E_8\ E_9\ E_{10}
$$

We want to find the probability that the 2nd event occurs at $E_2$ or $E_3$ or ... That means when two of these events occur, that game is over.
In reality, the probability of occurrence of a pair or even 3 and 4 events follow a trend of increase, reaching a peak and then decrease in the probability.
For the above example, the probability that the second event occurs at $E_1, E_2,\ldots,E_{10}$ is as follows:

0.0 0.02 0.05 0.07 0.06 0.04 0.3 0.02 0.01 0.01

Could you give me some hints on how to do it?

When I consider $P(E_1 \cap E_2)$, $P(E_2 \cap E_3)$, $P(E_3 \cap E_4)$, $P(E_4 \cap E_5)$, $P(E_5 \cap E_6), \ldots , P(E_9 \cap E_{10})$, it gives the same trend, but the probabilities are not correct because for example in $P(E_3 \cap E_4)$ I am not considering $E_1$ and $E_2$.

The point is that the probability of occurrence of individual events is decreasing, thus for instance 
$$
P(E_6\text{ is the 2nd occurrence in the sequence}) < P(E3\text{ is the 2nd occurrence in the sequence}) 
$$
because one of the events before $E_6$ has a higher likelihood to occur and to be the 2nd event of the pair.

When do I consider all the combination of any event before each event and that particular event, the peak of trend shifted forward and again it does not give a correct answer. It seems that there is a kind of dependency and memory in this sequence.